# Implementing km/h and m/s with user-defined literals

Tags: c++, c++11, user-defined-literals

I want to implement two [user-defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal), _kmh for kilometers per hour and _ms for meters per second. I already have two structs for that and the operator "" functions:

```
constexpr KMH operator "" _ms(long double val) {
    return KMH {static_cast<double>(val * 3.6)};
}
constexpr MS operator "" _kmh(long double val) {
    return MS {static_cast<double>(val / 3.6)};
}
```

I want it to implement it in a way that I can could do something like this:

```
void func(MS speed) {}

int main() {
    func(10.0_kmh); // this works
    func(10.0_ms); // this does not
}
```

I can't get the second call to work, because I can't implement it like this:

```
constexpr KMH operator "" _kmh(long double val) {
    return KMH {static_cast<double>(val)};
}
```

This obviously gives me the error

> error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded

Is there a way to implement what I want?

Comment: I think KMH and MS are going to need to be different types (not just typedeff'd).

Comment: @Galik: Well, they are both based on double, but are seperate structs.

Comment: I'd have only one type for speed with a base unit and the literal operators doing the conversion to that base unit.

Comment: I'd probably go for something more like `10.0_km/1_h` or `10.0_m/1_s`, both `operator/`s returning a `Speed` of some sort. Both of the first operands can be some `Length` type and the second can be `Time`. Of course feel free to use Boost.Units or other existing things.

Comment: @gartenriese Well maybe try casting them to your structs rather than doubles? (although I would have thought that would be implicit - not used this feature yet)

Comment: Another possible take on this requires your quantity object to track both value and unit (think back to high school physics, when all of your instructors were trying to get you to preserve units through the whole mathematical process).  That's not too hard, the challenge then becomes teaching the program that some units are multiples of other units.  I'll post an ideone in a minute

Comment: @Galik: All the examples I saw cast to double, so that should be fine, but thanks!

Comment: I came up with this (rudimentary) thing that preserves units in generic quantities.  It's kind of kludgey, and I'm not sure I'd ever actually use it for anything, but I might as well post it here because I spent time on it. You'd need to do a lot more with it before it became properly viable for any kind of real work, there are a lot of missing operators.  http://ideone.com/772vc9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [AProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/136208/aprogrammer) suggested, using only one basic struct for speed is a good solution.

```
struct speed {
    float m_val;
    constexpr speed(float val) : m_val{val} {}
    operator float() const { return m_val; }
};

constexpr speed operator "" _ms(long double val) {
    return speed {static_cast<float>(val)};
}
constexpr speed operator "" _kmh(long double val) {
    return speed {static_cast<float>(val) / 3.6f};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may add non explicit `operator MS()`

```
class KMH
{
public:
    operator MS() const { return {val / 3.6}; }

// your previous stuff
};
```

or non explicit `constructor` in `MS` which take `KMH`

```
class MS
{
public:
    constexpr MS(const KMH& kmh) : val(kmh.val * 3.6) {}

// your previous stuff
};
```

BTW, you may stick with only one struct (`MS`) and make all your `operator ""_ms`, `""_kmh` return `MS`

Comment: I didn't think of that! But I guess I will stick with only one struct for both MS and KMH, seems easier to me.